# Animate nouns: the very rare cases

Tags: склонение

I found special case declinations for the following types of nouns - but yet the tables didn't give example words.

Therefore I challenge you to give an example of ... (deviating declination of accusative plural give in brackets)

- A first declination male *animate* noun ending on -ий (-иев instead of -ия)
- A second declination *animate* noun ending on -ия (-ий instead of -ии)
- A third declination female *animate* noun ending on -ь (-ей instead of -и)

**Addendum**

*Inanimate* examples for the three special cases would be (in same order)

- санаторий
- Россия
- ночь

Comment: What tables do you use? Two first cases seem not to match the definitions in [this Wikipedia article](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%28%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%29#.D0.A1.D0.BA.D0.BB.D0.BE.D0.BD.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5_.D0.B8.D0.BC.D0.B5.D0.BD_.D1.81.D1.83.D1.89.D0.B5.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B2.D0.B8.D1.82.D0.B5.D0.BB.D1.8C.D0.BD.D1.8B.D1.85_.D0.B2_.D1.80.D1.83.D1.81.D1.81.D0.BA.D0.BE.D0.BC_.D1.8F.D0.B7.D1.8B.D0.BA.D0.B5). As for third declination: мать, дочь, выпь, выхухоль...

Comment: @Artemix these are from the most extensive table I have, which was taken from a textbook I sadly cannot retrace. Therefore I will add the deviations to my question.

Comment: Found a note in the wiki that the first and second declination are numbered differently in different textbooks (the first may become second and the second - the first).

Comment: @Artemix Kudos for the strange animals, they match, but мать and дочь are irregular anyway.

Comment: 1. Евгений, Валерий. 2. Мария, Виктория, София. 3. мышь, блядь, тварь.

Comment: Why do you call these patterns ‘very rare’,  ‘deviating’,  etc? They are perfectly regular and common.

Comment: Why ask for *accusative* plural when you essentially want **genitive** plural? Genitive has more patterns than you'd expect but they are mostly regular. For animate nouns, well, *гений, Мария, мышь* (-ия is more frequent for abstractions, not so much for people unless it is names).

Comment: @Shady_arc The genitive plural endings are the same for animate and inanimate nouns. It is the accusative plural where the deviation happens: inanimate sticks to nominative plural, while animate takes genitive form.

Comment: @DmitryAlexandrov Well, the cases I was asking here are at least rare in the sense of "rarely listed/explained". And they are deviating because they decline just like their inanimate friends, except their ending in accusative plural deviates.

Comment: I do not understand how it is any different from the words' generic behaviour. **All nouns in plural** have Accusative=Nomintive if they are inanimate and Accusative=Genitive if they are animate (note that in *singular* Acc=Nom if the noun is nominalised *neuter* adjective like "животное", which is, at least, unexpected). The exact pattern of genitive plural is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

1. Акакий, Лаврентий, Терентий, Вий! :-)
2. бестия, гаргулия :-)
3. выпь :-)

P.S. более правильная форма: гаргулья

Answer (score 2):

1. аграрий, викарий, гуманитарий, пролетарий
2. валькирия, гарпия, гурия, мумия, фурия
3. бездарь, бестолочь, выхухоль, дрянь, мразь, свекровь